# I wrote this method to delete duplicate elements of a linked list, but it shows segmentation fault, why?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, linked-list

```
Node* RemoveDuplicates(Node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
    {
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *ptr = head;
        Node *tmp = head->next;
        int a = ptr->data;
        int b = tmp->data;
        while (ptr->next != NULL)
        {
            if (a == b)
            {
                while (a == b)
                {
                    ptr->next = tmp->next;
                    tmp = tmp->next;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ptr = ptr->next;
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }

        }
        return head;
    }
}
```

GDB OUTPUT:

```
GDB trace:
Reading symbols from solution...done.
[New LWP 11656]
Core was generated by `solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  RemoveDuplicates (head=0x150fd00)
    at solution.cc:31
31            ptr->next=tmp->next;
#0  RemoveDuplicates (head=0x150fd00)
    at solution.cc:31
#1  main () at solution.cc:80
```

I wrote this code on hackerrank and its showing the following output, really can't understand why, please someone help me out!

Comment: A [mcve] please

Comment: First of all try some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). And then detail the algorithm on paper, and step through the code line by line in a debugger to make sure it does what it is supposed to do. If you do the last thing (stepping through the code in a debugger) you should be able to find the problem very quickly! Hint: You have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
        if (a == b)
        {
            while (a == b)
            {
                ptr->next = tmp->next;
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
```

When `a` is equal to `b` you execute the `while (a == b)`. Since you don't change `a` or `b` in the body of the `while`, you have an endless loop.

Sooner or later `tmp` will be `NULL` and your program crashes.

You probably wanted to update either `a` or `b` inside the loop. Further you need to check for `NULL` before doing `ptr->next = tmp->next`

Answer (score 0):

if `a` and `b` are same in below `if` condition tem=tmp->next gives segmentation fault.

```
if (a == b)
{
    while (a == b)
    {
        ptr->next = tmp->next;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
```

if `a` and `b` are not same then in `else` condition `tmp = tmp -> next` gives segmentation fault.

```
else
   {
      ptr=ptr->next;
      tmp=tmp->next;
   }
```

Because both `a` and `b` remain constant in whole loop. And this logic will check values of first two nodes only.
Make sure after checking for one node both `a` and `b` value must be changed.